# Wakanda SSL: Use a stronger certificate hash function than SHA-1?

Tags: ssl, wakanda

Following the [Wakanda SSL Documentation](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda-Server-Reference-Guide/Administrating-Wakanda-Server/Configuring-secure-connections-SSLTLS.300-952181.en.html), I've set up a self-signed certificate to test before I engage a certificate authority. However, Firefox lets me know that my webserver is using a SHA-1 certificate (below), which is undesirable- I want at least SHA-256.

Is there a way to control this; do I have any options here?

[image: Firefox Warning]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wakanda doesn't actually provide a certificate.
Wakanda uses the certificate you provide.

All you need to do is get a new certificate.

You can take your existing CSR to a certificate authority and purchase a signed certificate, and it will be SHA256. You can even use https://www.startssl.com and get a signed SHA256 certificate for free.

If you want to go self signed then just make sure to use the `-sha256` parameter like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```